# Make background image zoom with css3 transition, not work in chrome

Tags: html, css

I am working on "zoom" effect using a div like this:

```
<div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(image); background-position: 65% 50%;">
            <div class="content" style="margin-top: 150px">
                <h3>Blabla<br>Blablablablabla<br></h3>
                <p class="home5050">Blablablablabla.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-photo" href="urlsomething" style="color: black; background-color: white;">Blabla <span class="btnArrow">&gt;<span></span></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
    .highlight {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /*min-height: 800px;*/
  min-height: 520px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*padding-top: 200px;*/
  padding-top: 80px;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
}

.highlight:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    content: "";
}

.highlight{
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: auto 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover{
  background-size: auto 130%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}

.highlight:before{
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}

.highlight:hover:before{
 background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
 -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
 transition: background-color 3s ease; 
}
```

I found more css in the theme that makes references to highlight, maybe some problem with it? This working in firefox but not in chrome now.

https://jsfiddle.net/1v3epk6b/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're specifying `background-size` in 3 places but only 2 of them have the transition. Combine your rules for `.highlight` and remove the third `background-size`.

I don't know which rules you actually wanted, but perhaps like this:

```
.highlight:hover {
    background-size: auto 130%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
    transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
.highlight {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 520px;
    height: 800px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: auto 110%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
    transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xav8t479/2/

---

If you want the transition to start after 3 seconds, you need to use the `transition-delay` property:

```
.highlight:hover {
    transition-delay: 3s;
    /* ... */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xav8t479/3/

Comment: Yes, but transition effect dont trigger yet

Comment: They do for me. Every time I mouse over the background, it zooms in.

Comment: Yes but not make the transition effect in 3 seconds, The images are zoomed instantly, sorry my english

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Are you looking for `transition-delay`?

Comment: No, I just discover that this work forme in firefox and not in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

**This is a version without animation keyframes:
Are you lookin for this? It's working in Chrome.**

```css
.highlight:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2 ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  background-size: auto 130%;
}
.highlight {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2 ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  background-image:url(http://www.eahealthsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/EA_Health_On_Call_Compensation_8916.jpg);
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: auto 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  min-height: 520px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
  <div class="content" style="margin-top: 150px">
    <h3>Blabla<br>Blablablablabla<br></h3>
    <p class="home5050">Blablablablabla.</p>
    <a class="btn btn-photo" href="urlsomething" style="color: black; background-color: white;">Blabla <span class="btnArrow">&gt;<span></span></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I prefer use of transitions instead of animation

Comment: Try the new version. It's without animation keyframes and with transitions. Also it works with Chrome